# view folder won't show up using path.join?

Tags: node.js, express, npm, ejs

I'm trying to set up a view folder for ejs but it won't show up. My code is below:

```
//set up express
  const express = require("express");
  const app = express();

//set up ejs
  const path = require("path");
  app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));
  app.set("view engine", "ejs");
```

Here's the folder structure on my laptop:

[image: folder structure]

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: create it by your self.

Comment: Thank you @hoangdv! I did create one manually in the end but I would like to know if it's possible to create one using path.join, and if so, why it's not working in my code?

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: I run node index.js in the terminal. It runs with no error message. But I didn't see the folder that should be created.

Comment: In your terminal, let's run `mkdir views`

Comment: Yes, I didn't run `mkdir views` in the end and created the views folder manually. But I'm expecting the views folder will show up automatically after I run the code: `const path = require("path");`
`app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));` but it didn't. Do you know what happened?

Comment: Ohhh I think I know what's going on here...I had the wrong vision that `app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"))` is used to CREATE the views folder. That's why I thought something went wrong with my code when I didn't see the folder shown up. Actually, I still do need to create the views folder manually every time. Thank you @hoangdv for your patience! And please correct me if I'm wrong here :)